# Store dynamic matrix objects in an array C++ with template class

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a template class of a dynamic matrix. I want to ask the user for the number of matrices they want to add, and then create the matrix objects within a for loop through storing them in an array.

This is the class constructor:

```
template <class E> 
class Matrix{
public:
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    Matrix(int m, int n) {
        this->m = m;
        this->n = n;
        matrix = new E*[m];
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            matrix[i] = new E[n];
        }
    }
```

For that, the array must be of the template class type:

```
        std::cout<<"\nWho many matrices do you want to sum?"; std::cin>>numMxToSum;
        Matrix<float> *matricesToSum[numMxToSum];           
        
        for(int i=0; i<numMxToSum; i++) {
            matricesToSum[i] = Matrix<float> matrixObjToSum(m,n);
        }
```

But when I try to run it, I get:
**"[Error] expected primary-expression before 'matrixObjToSum'"**

How can I store multiple matrix objects inside an array?

Comment: Why not simply `std::vector<std::vector<E>> matrix`?  That takes care of the manual memory management.  Not only that, a `for` loop would no longer be necessary to initialize the data.

Comment: Side note: Arrays of pointers to arrays can really slow down a program. Often you're better off making one big array of `m*n` and perform the 2D to 1D translation in the accessor functions.

Comment: Are you aware that `matricesToSum` is an array of *pointers* to `Matrix`? Was that your intent?

Comment: Yes Bob, thanks for noticing. The problem is that if I remove the pointer it gives me the error: [Error] no matching function for call to 'Matrix<float>::Matrix()'

Comment: I think I will make a new post to learn how to create an array of template class object, because I get the error above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @albbeltran `Matrix<float> *matricesToSum[numMxToSum];` -- This is not valid C++. 
 [Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), not a runtime value such as `numMxToSum`.  The proper way to do this is `std::vector<Matrix<float>> matricesToSum(numMxToSum);`.

Comment: @albbeltran [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/PdG77E66n).  That entire code does what you're trying to do, both in declaring the number of matrices, and initializing all the matrices to a certain size.  This is even before you could add the optimization of using a single vector.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie. I'll use that syntax, I've never used std::vector before so I didn't know about it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that you don't even need the `m` and `n` member variables if you use `std::vector`.  In fact, I recommend you remove them.  A `std::vector` knows is own size by calling the `size()` function, so `m` and `n` are unnecessary.  Unnecessary variables meant to track the size of a vector is just a way to open yourself up to more bugs.  What if those variables miss when the vector is resized?  You now have a bug with those unnecessary size variables being out-of-sync with the actual size of the vector.

Comment: Why store the matrixes at all? Create a Matrix for the result and every time the user inputs a matrix add it to the result. No need to store the input past that point.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a syntax problem you should replace:

```
matricesToSum[i] = Matrix<float> matrixObjToSum(m,n);
```

To:

```
matricesToSum[i] = Matrix<float>(m,n);
```

Comment: You forgot a `new`. It's an array of pointer to `Matrix<float>`.